# Euler's method sage math don't know where to sart

Tags: sage

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yZA5.png)

I don't know where to start with this program

Comment: I do want to point out that the image says "don't just copy something from the internet".

Answer (score 0):

It says "start with a list of points called ..." so you should probably say, as Python/Sage syntax with starting a list of ordered pairs:

```
pointlist = [ (2, 1.5) ]
```

Since this appears to be a homework/exam question, I think that's more than enough help.  But you should note that it asks you to "write a loop", which hopefully you learned about and which is just normal Python loop syntax, and that you are asked to *append* points ... good luck.  Just reading the instructions and following them step by step often helps a lot - so that should work here as well.